# android : Tracking sleep mode from Band SDK without Microsoft Health Cloud API

Tags: android, sensors, microsoft-band, mobility

Am currently using microsoft-band for my app development in android. I need to track my sleep activity in the app without using Microsoft Health Cloud API. In Band SDK, there are certain parameters such as pedometer, heart rate, calories burned and sensor data such as accelerometer and gyroscope can be obtained. Is it possible to track sleep mode with Band SDK itself ?

If i am not wrong, Walk activity and Heart rate can be calculated from band SDK itself. Whereas if i am not able to track sleep activity from band SDK alone. Then the better idea would be going for Microsoft health API right ? to track all the three (Walk, Heart Rate, Sleep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Band SDK does not currently expose a means of (directly) tracking the sleep state of its wearer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply phil. So, the Microsoft health API is recommended for tracking that sleep activity right ? and also walking and heart rate !!!

Comment: Yes, you can use the Microsoft Health (REST) API to track sleep as a set of discrete events, as long as those sleep events have been synced with the service.  You can use the Band SDK to track steps and heart rate in real time (as long as you can maintain an active connection), or use the REST API to track them in summary over a longer period of time.